# Access crash dumps (Error Reporting) on Windows Phone 10 device

Tags: windows-phone, windows-10-mobile

Bing and Google came up with nothing.
I've activated the developer tools on the device (Lumia 950) and are saving as many crash dumps as possible.

When checking the file system on the device there is literally no logs there.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it, according to this article [Enable your device for development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn706236.aspx)

> You can find the dumps in your phone's storage in the Documents\Debug
>   folder.

However, dumps are collected for developer-signed apps only